# 現在流れている音の音量を取得したい。

Tags: android, java, android-mediaplayer

現在Androidアプリを開発しており、
アプリ内で音を再生中にその音の音量を数値で取得したいです。
例えば、音を再生中にタイマーイベントを0.1秒置きに張って音量取得をし、
その数値を元に波形表示をするようなことがしたいです。

再生している音データ自体はMediaPlayerクラス内に格納されています。

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.start();
```

Objective-Cで同じようなことは以下の方法で可能でした。

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
[player updateMeters];
float db= [player averagePowerFofChannel:0];
float power = pow(10, (0.05 * db));
```

お手数お掛けしますが、ご教授いただければと思います。

Comment: 音量という言葉は曖昧なので求めたいものが分かりませんが、少なくともiOSと同等のAPIはないので、`Visualizer`クラスを使ってFFTでdbを算出するか、Obj-Cで算出してるintensityならwave波形からでも出せると思います。

Comment: quesera2様
ご解答ありがとうございます。
Visualizerクラスを用いて波形表示できることは知っていたのですが、音声データをキャプチャしてdb算出という発想には至っておりませんでした・・・。
現在は教えていただきましたVisualizerクラスで音声データをキャプチャできましたので、あとはdbを算出して実装していきたいと思います。

この度は有力なご解答ありがとうございました。